# Twitter API error when try to post

Tags: php, oauth, twitter, twitter-oauth

```
$twitteroauth = new TwitterOAuth(YOUR_CONSUMER_KEY, YOUR_CONSUMER_SECRET, 'User_Token Access', 'user_token secret');  

$twitteroauth->post('statuses/update', array('status' => 'Hello Nettuts+'));
```

When I try to use this code, I am getting error

> Could not authenticate you

And my Status was also not updated. Why is it so?

Comment: Did you replace the oAuth tokens with the right ones?

Comment: yes i replace the oAuth tokens correctly

Comment: Are you sure you are not using the request token instead of the access token? Try the single user access token way of getting a token and see if that works: http://dev.twitter.com/pages/oauth_single_token

Comment: i have a web app , where users activity will be tweeted.The above tutorial works only for my twitter account:)

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your comment:

> I have a web app, where users' activity will be tweeted. The above tutorial works only for my twitter account

Of course you can only post tweets to your *own* account. Imagine what could happen if you can tweet ‘random’ messages to every account. I would not like that.

To tweet using others' accounts, you'll need *their* authentication keys.